# Create Namespace in redis by command line

Tags: database, redis, command, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu and I have REDIS database, I want to create namespace or database in REDIS but I couldn't find any command for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create database explicitly. Redis has already created 16 databases by default (you can change the number of databases with redis.conf).

These databases are named (indexed) with a number beginning from 0, and the default database you're using is *database 0*. If you want to operate on other databases, you can use the [select](http://redis.io/commands/select) command to switch between these databases. For example, switch to *database 1* with the following command.

```
select 1
```

After that, any subsequent commands will operate on *database 1*.

Answer (score 1):

Redis comes with 16 databases by default. You can select any of them using select command. **select 0**, if you want to have more than that you can change that in the redis.conf file. Under **GENERAL** section set the value of **databases** to your desired number. Then you need to start your redis server with the config file ie, **redis-server redis.conf**